# Как получить значение из класса?

Tags: wordpress, классы, wordpress-плагины

Есть задача по выводу значения поля "Страна", которое было назначено в аккаутах пользователей, заданых через плагин [Ultimate Member](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-member/).
Пытаюсь получить значение этих стран на обычной странице, но в базу пишется не имя страны, а её код.

```
<p class="account_country h6"><?php
  $country_code = get_user_meta($user_id, 'country', true);
 // $country_name = Builtin::get('countries')[$country_code];
   echo $country_code; ?></p>
```

Код страны выводит правильно, но как превратить его в читабельное название? Я нашел в корне плагина класс `wp-content/plugins/ultimate-member/includes/core/class-builtin.php`, который занимается его трансформацией, но не могу понять, как его применить.

[image: Class2]

Мой вариант - получить в переменную `$country_name` - вылетает с ошибкой.

Comment: `Мой вариант - получить в переменную $country_name - вылетает с ошибкой` это же не статический метод, Вы не можете к нему обратиться таким образом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте такой код

`UM()->builtin()->get_data( 'countries' )[ $country_code ];`

Comment: Что-то не работает. Ломаеться всё. Класс выглядит так https://github.com/ultimatemember/ultimatemember/blob/master/includes/core/class-builtin.php

Comment: @BlackStar1991 можете попробовать `UM()->builtin()->get( 'countries' )[ $country_code ];`

Comment: Да, спасибо это работает.